# Range scan using thrift java api Hbase

Tags: java, hbase, thrift

I have 10 million rows in hbase and I would like to do range scan for retrieval process. Currently we are using java thrift api to connect to hbase. I know the hbase shell command for range scan

```
scan 'tablename', {STARTROW => '639415', ENDROW => '639415'}
```

Can any one tell me how to achieve this using java thrift api?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why do you use thrift api, not native java api ?

You can find a good tutorial in cloudera blog, explains thrift api, and  this link is about Scan https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-use-the-hbase-thrift-interface-part-3-using-scans/

By the way, in your example above, start and stop rows are same, since stop row is not included in hbase scan, it won't return any result.

Comment: The link is no more accessible. The new link is https://clouderatemp.wpengine.com/blog/2014/04/how-to-use-the-hbase-thrift-interface-part-3-using-scans/